# JS - PHP - Build an Array of Data From the Values of a Specific HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that a user can insert values of a text field using an auto complete input tag method (something similar to the Stackoverflow tags input during the submission process of a question). It instantly builds an HTML div similar to the below:

```
<div name="new-words[]" id="new-words" multiple="multiple" class="hidden">
    <option value="Flower" id="newWord_H0uTTbUsLW8R3fSpfMw16JnvpVQ9zhdW" class="selected" selected="selected">Flower</option>
    <option value="Animal" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDcCd2nUMpz1mc1ssVLAXgIVw" class="selected" selected="selected">Animal</option>
    <option value="Tiger" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDjijms23mmoAOPPL009AOOOO" class="selected" selected="selected">Tiger</option>
    ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div name="new-words[]" id="new-words" multiple="multiple" class="hidden">
    <input value="Flower" id="newWord_H0uTTbUsLW8R3fSpfMw16JnvpVQ9zhdW" class="selected" selected="selected" />
    <input value="Animal" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDcCd2nUMpz1mc1ssVLAXgIVw" class="selected" selected="selected" />
    <input value="Tiger" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDjijms23mmoAOPPL009AOOOO" class="selected" selected="selected" />
    ...
</div>
```

My question is how can I build an array of data from the values of the `option` or `input` tag (i.e. Flower, Animal, Tiger) and send the array to a PHP file (or different URL) for further processing before inserting the data into the database? Thanks for your your help.

Comment: Why are you inserting option tag inside a div

Comment: @Ankit, it can also be input tag as well, pls see the question again .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array and then loop through your options, pushing each value to the array. You'll have to use AJAX to send the array to php.

```js
var nw = document.getElementById('new-words'),
  options = nw.children,
  toPhp = [];

function loops(items, fn, onLoopComplete) {
  var i;
  try {
    if (items && items.length) {
      i = items.length;
    } else {
      throw new Error(items + ' is required to have a length');
    }

    if (i > -1) {
      do {
        if (items[i] !== undefined) {
          fn(i);
          /* console.log(i + ' is the current iteration'); */
        }
      }
      while (--i >= 0);
    }
    if (typeof onLoopComplete === 'function') {
      onLoopComplete(items.length);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}

loops(options, function(i) {
  toPhp.push(options[i].value);
});


alert(toPhp);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div name="new-words[]" id="new-words" multiple="multiple" class="hidden">
    <option value="Flower" id="newWord_H0uTTbUsLW8R3fSpfMw16JnvpVQ9zhdW" class="selected" selected="selected">Flower</option>
    <option value="Animal" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDcCd2nUMpz1mc1ssVLAXgIVw" class="selected" selected="selected">Animal</option>
    <option value="Tiger" id="newWord_ZxFWGZrgDjijms23mmoAOPPL009AOOOO" class="selected" selected="selected">Tiger</option>
    ...
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```